# python list math index variable

Tags: python, list, math, mutable

This works the way I want

```
a = [1,8,10]
b = list([a])

a = [0,8,10]

b.append(a)

a = [0,0,10]
b.append(a)

print(b)
```

giving me the list that I want:

> > > [[1, 8, 10], [0, 8, 10], [0, 0, 10]]

I need to change the values using variables based on the index of the list like  this

```
a = [1,8,10]
b = list([a])

a[0] = a[0] - 1

b.append(a)

print(b)
```

and I get this result :

```
[[0, 8, 10], [0, 8, 10]]
```

My entire point is to keep track of my moves for creating the nim game. I think I see how setting a[0] = a[0] - 1 changes the value in both places even when I tried using deep copy but I am stumped on how else to get the answer. I am sure it is obvious but I don't know what key words to use to search for the solution, so please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using deepcopy should work -- I suspect you were just using it in the wrong place.

The danger of using a single list as a template, as you were doing with `a` is that if you mutate it, you could end up changing the lists you've already appended to `b`. One way to get around this problem is to always create a new copy of `a` whenever you want to change it.

```
import copy

b = []

a = [1,8,10]
b.append(a)

a2 = copy.deepcopy(a)  
a2[0] = a2[0] - 1
b.append(a2)

print(b)
```

Another way might be to make a copy of `a` whenever you append it to `b`, so that you don't have to keep creating new variables:

```
import copy

b = []

a = [1,8,10]
b.append(copy.deepcopy(a))

a[0] = a[0] - 1
b.append(copy.deepcopy(a))

print(b)
```

The common point between these two different approaches is that we always append any given list exactly *once*. In your code, you append the same list multiple times to `b`. That means that whenever you change `a`, it appears as if you changed *everything* in `b`.

In the two examples I provided, I append a list only *once*, and copy it if I need to make changes. By doing so, I ensure that each list inside `b` is unique, and avoid running into the issue you encountered.

As a side note, another way to create a copy of a list is to do `a2 = a[:]`. The `a[:]` is telling Python to get a list slice of `a` starting from the beginning of the list to the end, essentially copying it. Note that this is a shallow copy, not a deep copy. However, since your lists contain only numbers, a shallow copy should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! Appending the same list multiple times makes sense and now that I  know how to properly append the new list you are right the following also works.                                          b = []

a = [1,8,10]
b.append(a[:])

a[0] = a[0] - 1
b.append(a[:])

a[1] = a[1] - 8
b.append(a[:])

print(b)